# Where can I get a vector Stack Overflow logo?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-exchange, logo

Is there any [vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_graphics) logo file for Stack Overflow that is openly available?

I could use it to make some wallpapers.

Comment: If you do make some Desktop wallpapers I would LOVE to see them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[SVG Versions of the Logos](https://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos)

Make sure to read usage guideline also.

Answer (score 2):

[Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) includes a number of Stack Exchange logos as part of the (vectorized) font:

- `fa-stack-exchange` (Unicode F18D; created V4.0)

  [image]
- `fa-stack-overflow` (Unicode F16C; created V3.2)

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find the logos here:
https://stackexchange.com/about/logos

Prior to use, please read the following guideline:
https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: The question asks for the logo in `.svg` format but the only downloads on the page you suggest are for `.png` files.

Comment: @NoviceSEMetaGeek The question asks for _vector_. SVG is far from the only vector format. EPS is provided on the page and is vector.

Comment: And where can we find all the other site logos?